# How to create .drawing file for PencilKit?

Tags: ios, swift, frameworks, apple-pencil, pencilkit

[image]

If you look at Apple's `PencilKit` Sample, you'll noticed apple used a dataset file called `Notes.dataset` to save `Pencilkit` draws. Inside the `Notes.dataset`, it contains a general json file for Asset Catalogue.

But more interesting, there is a file called `color.drawing`, which saves the actual data produced by `Pencilkit`. My question is, how do you create this file as a developer? For example, I want to create a tutorial using `Pencilkit` and save it as a ".drawing" file, to load up on first launch.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`PKDrawing` is a model layer of `PencilKey` (and it is opaque), and here is API to store/restore that model:

```
   func dataRepresentation() -> Data // << to store data in file
   init(data: Data) throws // << to restore from data read from file
```